# Fade out process of textview animation not working properly

Tags: android, animation, textview, fade

So I have a `textview` at the top of my screen and eight buttons in the middle. What I would like to happen is for the `textview` to slide in from the right (animation) and then whenever the user clicks a button it makes the `textview` fade out, changes the text, and then fade back in with the new text. The fading back in and changing the text works fine, but instead of fading out the `textview` just disappears. The `textview` also has a problem with the slide in from the left animation in `onCreate` so i figured it may be something I am missing to do with the `textview`. Here is my code, someone please help mehh!!

```
private void AnimationMethodForButtons(TextView TitleArea, int explanation){
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(TitleArea, "alpha",  1.0f, 0.0f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(3000);
    fadeOut.start();
    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(TitleArea, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(3000);
    TitleArea.setText(explanation);
    fadeIn.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `start()` call is asynchronous. You should be using an `AnimatorListener` if you want to do something at the end of an animation.

```
private void AnimationMethodForButtons(final TextView title, final int explaination){
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(title, "alpha",  1.0f, 0.0f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(3000);

    final ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(title, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(3000);

    fadeOut.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            title.setText(explaination);
            fadeIn.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    fadeOut.start();
}
```